# Mobilefirst 8 cordova app crashed when add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-ios

We create a simple cordova project

our platform info :

```
cordova-ios 4.5.5
cordova-cli 8.1.2
```

cordova plugin list :

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2019091217 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
```

the app cashed when run in the simulator , the error message as shown below

[image]

**Update:**

Test cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2019120904 version and still crash

Answer (score 3):

We discovered the issue recently with WKWebview and will be releasing the fix to cordova mfp plugin very soon.